# Show users pictures who have flagged a node

Tags: 7, views, flags

I have a event node and a flag to join the event.
I want to show the user pictures who have flagged "Join event"

This is what I have done so far

1.Created a Node View

2.Added a relationship Flags: Node flag (select the required flags
    and tick "Include only tagged Nodes"

3) Added another Relationship Flags : User

4) Added Relationship "Content Author"

4) Added contextual filter: Content: Nid > 
Content id from URL > Specify validation criteria > Flaggable = Join Event

5 ) Add field User Picutre

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll have to create a *user* view, displayed as a block, and use the flag relationship to the nodes. Then use a contextual filter, taking the node NID from the URL as default.

Comment: @ollie You can ID from URL when its about a page. What if it is about a block not a page.